# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' soundplaying in python

Tags: python, windows, audio

I am a beginner
i was trying to play music in my python file
when i intalled playsoud and used it
i faced this problem

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

please solve my problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's likely a problem with your playsound installation.